# Cordova build error with Phonegap Desktop

Tags: cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I am trying to use Phonegap desktop app to install my cordova app. When I click on "Open existing project" and select my cordova project I get this error

```
Uncaught node.js Error

Error: Invalid XML: ﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<widget  
  xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"  
 xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 id="com.crondale.tippnett" version="1.0.1"     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"> 
  <name>TippNett</name> 
 <description>TippNett er et system for å som bidrar til bedre massebalanse. Systemet finner anlegg i nærheten med motsatt massebehov. Det bidrar til kortere kjørelengde og raskere anleggsutførsel. Du sparer penger, i tillegg til at miljøet blir spart for CO2 utslipp.</description> 
 <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">Crondale</author> 
 <content src="index.html" /> 
 <access origin="*" /> 
 <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" /> 
 <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.0" /> 
 <preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="8.1" /> 
 <preference name="target-device" value="handset" /> 
 <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" /> 
 <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.5.2" /> 
 <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.12" /> 

 <icon src="res/icons/icon.png" /> 

 <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" /> 
 <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" /> 
 <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" /> 
 <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" /> 

 <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />  
 <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />  

 <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />  
 <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
```

```
at Error (native)
   at Function.x.extend.error (file:///C:/Users/mohsin/AppData/Local/Temp/nw3608_7791/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4:3552)
at Function.x.extend.parseXML (file:///C:/Users/mohsin/AppData/Local/Temp/nw3608_7791/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4:4018)
at parseProjectConfig (file:///C:/Users/mohsin/AppData/Local/Temp/nw3608_7791/js/project-create-open-handlers.js:250:42)
at file:///C:/Users/mohsin/AppData/Local/Temp/nw3608_7791/js/project-create-open-handlers.js:241:13
at fs.js:289:14
at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:97:15)
```

Can anyone help me with the error? Is something wrong in my config file?

Comment: hello install node.js software into your system.

Comment: open your command prompt (CMD) and type     node -v

Comment: This is the version of node I have v0.12.7

Comment: And I have tried and ran the sample project which comes with phone gap desktop app and it works.